# How to dynamically wire up Repositories with custom DataSources?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, datasource

So I have a fairly standard Spring Boot application using JavaConfig and JPA to wire up services and repositories. However, one non-standard aspect of the application is a requirement to spin up isolated cloud databases on demand to keep client data separate for legal reasons.

I have a simple ClientService with some Repositories injected, and my goal is to create some sort of factory where I can request a version of this ClientService, specific to each client, that has a custom DataSource injected into all of the repositories. Spring Boot, which is normally wonderful for wiring things up, has made things more confusing because its hard to see whats going on behind the scenes.

What would be the best way to approach this? My first idea is a bean called ClientServiceFactory with a method getClientService(Client client). Its easy enough for me to create the custom DataSource for this client - the hard part is how I can return an instance of ClientService, with all of the other things automatically injected, but forcing all the repository beans to use this datasource. Naturally ClientService would no longer be a singleton, but instead I would store a map internally of Client > ClientService.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A hacky solution: you can create a custom delegating datasource that will delegate to a real client-specific datasource depending on, say, some threadlocal variable that you will set based on your Client. I don't like this. :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you would need to implement a Multi-tenant approach.

I blogged about this topic at: [Multi-tenant applications using Spring Boot, JPA, Hibernate and Postgres](http://tech.asimio.net/2017/01/17/Multitenant-applications-using-Spring-Boot-JPA-Hibernate-and-Postgres.html)

Basically this are the steps to configure the persistence layer for Multi-tenancy:

- Hibernate, JPA and datasources properties:

**application.yml**

```
...
multitenancy:
  dvdrental:
    dataSources:
      -
        tenantId: TENANT_01
        url: jdbc:postgresql://172.16.69.133:5432/db_dvdrental
        username: user_dvdrental
        password: changeit
        driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
      -
        tenantId: TENANT_02
        url: jdbc:postgresql://172.16.69.133:5532/db_dvdrental
        username: user_dvdrental
        password: changeit
        driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
...
```

**MultiTenantJpaConfiguration.java**

```
 ...
 @Configuration
 @EnableConfigurationProperties({ MultiTenantDvdRentalProperties.class, JpaProperties.class })
 @ImportResource(locations = { "classpath:applicationContent.xml" })
 @EnableTransactionManagement
 public class MultiTenantJpaConfiguration {

   @Autowired
   private JpaProperties jpaProperties;

   @Autowired
   private MultiTenantDvdRentalProperties multiTenantDvdRentalProperties;
 ...
 }
```

**MultiTenantDvdRentalProperties.java**

```
...
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "multitenancy.dvdrental")
public class MultiTenantDvdRentalProperties {

  private List<DataSourceProperties> dataSourcesProps;
  // Getters and Setters

  public static class DataSourceProperties extends org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties {

    private String tenantId;
    // Getters and Setters
  }
}
```

- Datasources beans:

**MultiTenantJpaConfiguration.java**

```
 ...
 public class MultiTenantJpaConfiguration {
 ...
   @Bean(name = "dataSourcesDvdRental" )
   public Map<String, DataSource> dataSourcesDvdRental() {
       ...
   }
 ...
 }
```

- Entity manager factory bean:

**MultiTenantJpaConfiguration.java**

```
 ...
 public class MultiTenantJpaConfiguration {
 ...
   @Bean
   public MultiTenantConnectionProvider multiTenantConnectionProvider() {
       ...
   }

   @Bean
   public CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver currentTenantIdentifierResolver() {
       ...
   }

   @Bean
   public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean(MultiTenantConnectionProvider multiTenantConnectionProvider,
     CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver currentTenantIdentifierResolver) {
       ...  
   }
 ...
 }
```

- Transaction manager bean:

**MultiTenantJpaConfiguration.java**

```
 ...
 public class MultiTenantJpaConfiguration {
 ...
   @Bean
   public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean) {
       ...
   }

   @Bean
   public PlatformTransactionManager txManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
       ...
   }
 ...
 }
```

- Spring Data JPA and transaction support configuration:

**applicationContent.xml**

```
...
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.asimio.dvdrental.dao" transaction-manager-ref="txManager" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" proxy-target-class="true" />
...
```

**ActorDao.java**

```
public interface ActorDao extends JpaRepository<Actor, Integer> {
}
```

Depending on your needs something like this could be done:

```
...
@Autowired
private ActorDao actorDao;
...

DvdRentalTenantContext.setTenantId("TENANT_01");
this.actorDao.findOne(...);
...

// Or
DvdRentalTenantContext.setTenantId("TENANT_02");
this.actorDao.save(...);
...
```

Setting the tenantId could be done in a servlet filter / Spring MVC interceptor / thread via ThreadLocal that is going to execute the JPA operation, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up with a similar solution to this and it works!

Answer (score 2):

You may not be able to achieve this direectly. Since the Repositories are tightly coupled with EntityManagers and EntityManagers are tightly coupled with Datasources, implies that Repositories are tightly coupled with Datasources. You may not be able to create repositories at spring boot up.

You can create multiple JPARepositorySets for Different Datasources at start time. Lets say you need a UserRepository. You have 2 datasources DS1, DS2.

You can create Two Entity Managers EM1, EM2 for both datasources.

```
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em1() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(ds1());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.pkg1.entities.user" });
        return em;
    }

public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em2() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(ds2());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.pkg1.entities.user" });
        return em;
    }
```

At runtime depending on the client, your factory bean could create the repository for you, and return the repository as below.

```
public UserRepository getClientSpecificUserRepository(Client client){
    SimpleJpaRepository<User, Long> userRepository = null;
    if(client.name.equals("ABC")){
        userRepository = new SimpleJpaRepository<User, Serializable>(
    User.class, em1);
    } else (client.name.equals("ABC")){
        userRepository = new SimpleJpaRepository<User, Serializable>(
    User.class, em2);
    }
    return userRepository;
}
```

So ultimately create multiple EntityManagers for all your clients at context startup. And Factory returns the Repository bean at runtime depending on the client

Comment: Thank you - while I don't see why this wouldn't have worked, I opted with a dynamic routing data source so I didn't need to create any beans myself